# What is ActionScript 3 contentloaderinfo?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, addeventlistener

I am building an ActionScript 3 loader, which display the progress of Flash loading an external script. Here is a snippet of my code that works perfectly, but I am a little confused at to why I need it:

```
this.SWFLoader = new Loader();
this.SWFLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, trackProgress);
this.SWFLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
this.SWFLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadError);
```

As you can see, I have three event listeners, each for listening for different events triggered during the loading process.

In regards to the above snippet, here is what I am  unsure of:

1. What is the `contentloaderinfo` object?
2. What properties does the `contentloaderinfo` object contain?
3. Why can't I just use `this.SWFLoader.addEventListener()`?
4. When is it appropriate to use `contentloaderinfo`?

This is a topic I have been pretty confused about, and I haven't ever gotten a good explanation of it. Sorry for the crash list of questions. I will reward any and all good answers.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a `Loader` class to do your loading, and `contentLoaderInfo` is an object within that class that keeps track of some basic info about what's being loaded. Some of its properties are `bytesLoaded`, `bytesTotal`, `url`, `loaderURL`, and `applicationDomain`. The most commonly-used by far are `bytesLoaded` and `bytesTotal`, which give you a convenient percentage of what's loaded. Those are updated every time `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` is called, which leaves you only a few graphical elements away from a preloader.

The `contentLoaderInfo` object also has other handy events that you can subscribe to (like you are in your example) to know when the load process starts, updates, finishes, and/or even fails.

You can visit the AS3 documentation to get much more detail:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#contentLoaderInfo

Confusingly enough, `contentLoaderInfo` is a `LoaderInfo` object, so you can see its properties and methods here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html

You can't use `this.SWFLoader.addEventListener()` because SWFLoader doesn't fire that event. Instead, its much more loading-friendly child (`contentLoaderInfo`) does that -- hence the code working as it does.

It's appropriate to use `contentLoaderInfo` when you need to take advantage of the methods or properties that it makes available to you. That may sound like a dodgy answer, but it's true. Typically, you'll write functions to update on-stage elements that keep the user clued into what's going on in the loading department -- exactly like you are now.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you find the way it works bothersome, you can also extend Loader, then have Loader listen for and redispatch these events.  If you use your extended Class, you can then listen directly to it, which the Law of Demeter would suggest is better.